# Logic regarding array elements subtraction and comparison

Tags: java, logic

I wrote codes for the following question but the output is not as expected. I don't know if there is something wrong with my code. Logic seems fine. Can anyone see if there is something wrong with my code.

Given an array of scores sorted in increasing order, return true if the array contains 3 adjacent scores that differ from each other by at most 2, such as with {3, 4, 5} or {3, 5, 5}.

My source code is as follows:

```
public boolean scoresClump(int[] scores) {

    boolean result = false;

    for(int i=0; i<scores.length-2; i++){
        if((scores[i+1]-scores[i])<=2 && (scores[i+2]-scores[i+1])<=2){
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

[This](http://codingbat.com/prob/p194530) is the link to the question.

Comment: -scoresClump({3, 4, 5}) → true
-scoresClump({3, 4, 6}) → false
-scoresClump({1, 3, 5, 5}) → true

These are the test arrays

Comment: output not as expected meaning.. ?? I think you may need scores.length-2 ..

Comment: you can try the code at this [link](http://codingbat.com/prob/p194530)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Your previous post was not taking into account the delta between the non-adjacent values.

```
public boolean scoresClump(int[] scores) {
  boolean result = false;

  for(int i=0; i<scores.length-2; i++){
      if((scores[i+2]-scores[i])<=2){
          result = true;
          break;
      }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: The max diff between all 3 value must be <=2. This means that the value at index x and the value at index x+2 can only differ by 2. If you only check `x against x+1` and `x+1 against x+2`, you have not checked the difference between `x and x+2`

Comment: so the question was asking that the first and the last number of a number triplet should not differ by more than 2 rather than each member differing from each other by more than 2 as you go from left to right?

Comment: `return true if the array contains 3 adjacent scores that differ from each other by at most 2` -- which is why (3,4,6) should result in a false

Comment: @JohnB Even though the three tests given pass, your code will fail for anything like {3, 10, 5}. So it's not really instructive. Sure, it's easily fixable, but then you get code duplication. You must check all three unique pairs, and this number explodes for the generalization towards longer clumps.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the question states: `Given an array of scores sorted in increasing order`

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop should be `for(int i=0; i<scores.length-2; i++){` otherwise you will get an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

Also, your `break` should be in the `true` conditional not the `false` one. Currently your code exists the loop after the first set of 3 elements that do not match the condition.

Also, if they are already sorted in increasing order there is no need to do the `Math.abs`

Comment: i have readjusted the code. Still no point. I have attached the link to the question now.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you got an error or unexpected behaviour you should describe what it is (e.g. expected and real output).

In your case I can spot at least one error in your code: you access in your loop scores[i+2]. As I goes up to length-1, you access length+1. Even accessing length+0 is already an error, as the last element has index length-1. You didnt show your complete code, but I assume that the due to the thrown exception the result is in the calling function interpreted as false.

Furthermore the two checks are not necessary, one check is enough, as you would perform the next check with the next iteration.

Comment: This is my edited code:
 public boolean scoresClump(int[] scores) {
  
  boolean result = false;
  
  for(int i=0; i<scores.length-2; i++){
   if((scores[i+1]-scores[i])<=2 && (scores[i+2]-scores[i+1])<=2){
    result = true;
    break;
   }
  }
  
  return result;
 }

It still outputs true where it should be false.
This is the test link [link](http://codingbat.com/prob/p194530)

Comment: Don't post updated code as a comment or link. Update the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    public boolean scoresClump(int[] scores) {
boolean result=false;
for(int i=0; i<scores.length-2; i++){
        if(Math.abs(scores[i]-scores[i+1])<=2 &&
        Math.abs(scores[i+1]-scores[i+2])<=2 &&
        Math.abs(scores[i]-scores[i+2])<=2){
            result=true;
        }
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: why should scoresClump({3, 4, 6}) should be false?

Comment: that's why i am puzzled. I don't know if the sample test questions with answers are corrupted.

Comment: the delta between 3 & 6 is 3 not <= 2. I have posted an answer that passes the on-line test